# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0

Tags: json

I am trying parse some json so I can get the different parts of the json.  When I use the following code

```
JSONObject jsonOutput = new JSONObject( aResponse.getEntity(String.class) );
```

I'm getting the error :

> org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0

`aResponse.getEntity(String.class)` returns the json below....

```
{
  "list": {
    "access_level": "readonly",
    "address": "995@mg.lmsnet.com",
    "created_at": "Tue, 19 Apr 2016 04:01:05 -0000",
    "description": "",
    "members_count": 0,
    "name": "995"
  },
  "message": "Mailing list has been created"
}
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?  I was able to validate the json with an on line json validator

Comment: Do you want us to guess which language this is, and which library/ies you are using? Always provide exact versions of everything relevant.

Comment: Doh!  Sorry.  I'm using Java and the org.json library.

Comment: I'm also using Jersey for some Rest work.  Not sure if that is able to parse the JSON or not.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was get a string variable and the error went away.

```
String tempStr;

ClientResponse aResponse = CreateMailingList( "9967" );
**tempStr = aResponse.getEntity( String.class);**
JSONObject jsonOutput = new JSONObject( tempStr ); 
system.out.println( jsonOutput );
```